# Pandas: Replace all strings in lowercase in a column with None

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a data set with a column called 'names', which includes strings that aren't names. These all are written in **lowercase**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Chris Z', 'Hulk Hogan', 'notaname',
                             'whateven']})
```

Expected output:

```
     names
0    Chris Z
1    Hulk Hogan
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: names, dtype: object
```

I want to replace them with NaN and I have tried this:

```
df['names'] = df['names'].replace(r'[a-z]{2}', None, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

But this replaces all the entries in the column, including those starting with capital letters. Can you please advise a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`mask`** with **`^[a-z]+$`** as your regular expression:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Chris Z', 'Hulk Hogan', 'notaname', 'whateven']})

df.names.mask(df.names.str.match(r'^[a-z]+$'))

0       Chris Z
1    Hulk Hogan
2           NaN
3           NaN
Name: names, dtype: object
```

If there are spaces in some of the lowercase strings, just use **`^[a-z\s]+$`** instead.

```
^            # Asserts position at beginning of string
[  
  a-z        # Matches any lowercase character 1 or more times
]+           
$            # Asserts position at end of string
```

Answer (score 3):

Without regex, you can compare a series with a lower case version of itself:

```
df.loc[df['names'] == df['names'].str.lower(), 'names'] = np.nan

print(df['names'])

0       Chris Z
1    Hulk Hogan
2           NaN
3           NaN
Name: names, dtype: object
```